# Xcode 5 simulator cannot be installed, does not show up in xcode

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode5

In Xcode 5, i have a problem with installing simulators. They don`t show up in the downloads section of preferences for Xcode. And the 6.1 simulator cannot be run when it says its installed. Only shows up with a question mark besides it. When i click check and install, it says nothing new found. How to fix this?

[image]

When i try to run an app, no simulators show as installed:

[image]

Comment: If you don't find a quicker solution, you could always try deleting Xcode and downloading again from the Mac AppStore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows you installed all the simulators.

Just **Quit** the Xcode and open again. It wil show you a window same as below.

[image]

Also please cross check that, the downlaoded SDK's are available under `Application->Xcode.app->right-click->Show Package Contents

 ->Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs`

Also cross check the Base SDK and Target devices.

[image]

Comment: It does not show any installed simulators when i try to run an universal ios6&7 project, see update to question

Comment: please cross check that, the downlaoded SDK's are available under Application->Xcode.app->right-click->Show Package Contents->Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, nothing was in those folders, so i decided to reinstall xcode from scratch